# Proof of the Triangle Inequality for the $\infty$-norm

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I am trying to show that $$\|x\|_{\infty}=\max_{i=1,..,n}|x_i|$$ satisfies the triangle inequality, where $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $x_i\in\mathbb{R}$ for each $i=1,..,n$.

For all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
\begin{align}
\|x+y\|_{\infty}&=\max_{i=1,..,n}|x_i+y_i| \\
&\leq \max_{i=1,..,n}(|x_i|+|y_i|) \tag{1}\\
&=\max_{i=1,..,n}|x_i|+\max_{i=1,..,n}|y_i| \\
&=\|x\|_{\infty}+\|y\|_{\infty}
\end{align}

I have used the triangle inequality for scalars, $|a+b|\leq |a|+|b| \ \ \forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, in step $(1)$. I am unsure if this is a legitimate step.

Comment: The step after $(1)$ should also be $\le$.

Comment: @player3236 Why is that? Isn't this just a distribution property?

Comment: In the step (1), you are choosing the max of $|x_i|+|y_i|$ for the same $i$. The $|x_i|, |y_i|$ chosen may not be the largest.

Answer (score 1):

If you denote $i^* = \arg\max_{i=1,..,n}|x_i+y_i|$ then:

\begin{equation}
\|x+y\|_{\infty}=\|x_{i^*}+y_{i^*}\| \leq \|x_{i^*}\| + \|y_{i^*}\| \leq \max_{i=1,..,n}\|x_i\|+\max_{i=1,..,n}\|y_i\| = \|x\|_{\infty}+\|y\|_{\infty}.\end{equation}